# How to set a svelte store to an object array

Tags: arrays, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

Hello I am requesting a json file from a flask server, after processing the response I know have the json file showing up in the console.log.
The json file contains and array of objects of type advisor:

```js
export type advis = {
    Advisory: string;
    Teacher: string;
    Room: string;
};
```

I am not sure if I am completely understanding svelte stores but I initialized the store with an empty array of these objects.

```js
let advisRoomInit: advis[] = [];
// Init data stores
export const advisoryRooms = writable(advisRoomInit);
```

After getting the data back I then try and set the res from the array to the store like so

```js
onMount(
        async () => {
            try {
                const ad = await request(AdvisoryEndPoint); // Now this will wait till it finished
                let AD : advis[] = ad
                console.log(AD)
                advisoryRooms.set(AD)
                console.log(advisoryRooms);
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
)
```

While the first `console.log(AD)` returns the object array while the result of printing the just set store value returns `{}`

If anyone could help me in setting my object array to svelte store that would be very helpful as I have a deadline at 7:55 tmr morning and it is currently 23:00, I am the first red bull in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
console.log(advisoryRooms);
```

will print the store object. Prepend a `$` to access the store value

```js
console.log($advisoryRooms);
```

docs: ["Prefix stores with $ to access their values"](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values)

Comment: Technically that is "prepend".

Comment: @H.B. of course :) Thx!